# How to look for the first returned value in a JSON?

Tags: json, api, automation

I'm currently working on API testing. I have this sample JSON below. The JSON response is **changing** (same schema, different values), so the logic is, how do I search for the **first JSON value** that returns the `Open this message` and get the value of `id` that is `3328367679` ?

```
[
    {
        "id": 3328367679,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328364404,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Another message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328363502,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328357254,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
      "id": 3328349654,
      "inbox_id": 35584,
      "subject": "Open this message"
    }
  ]
```

After a while, the response will be: (has the same id but different data index)

```
[
    {
        "id": 3394784853,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Another message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328367679,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328364404,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Another message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328363502,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    },
    {
        "id": 3328357254,
        "inbox_id": 35584,
        "subject": "Open this message"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

> The find() method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

Presuming you have a callback on a `fetch()` giving a `response` that is in json format as shown,

```js
const id = response.find(item => item.subject === 'Open this message').id
```